# Почему в окне не появляется alert?

Tags: javascript, функции, alert

Прошу подсказать, почему при вызове в консоли следующей функции не всплывает окно alert?

```js
function func1 () {
  alert("some text");
}
```

Comment: Нужно вызвать эту функцию func1();

Comment: точно, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вы объявили функцию, теперь её нужно вызвать.

```js
function func1 () {
  alert("some text");
}

func1();
```

Comment: Да, разобрался, благодарю!